# Android exported Service forbid unauthorized app binding

Tags: android, service

Is there any way to make an exported Service reject binding when the caller app's packageName is not in my white-list? Or in another way, how can I get the caller app's packageName in my Service when it is bind?

ps:

1. android:permission is useless because any app can declare the permission string in manifest.
2. With the packageName, I can verify the APK's signature to make sure it is official version.

Comment: If you think permissions are useless, why do you think package name is any better?  I can make my package any name I want.  You may want a signature level permission-  that will only allow apps to use it if signed by the same certificate.

Comment: Yes you can fake your package name, but you can't fake your app's signature. And, it's impossible to use same certificate to sign the caller app unless its also develop by me(or my team).

Comment: I can't, because the caller app is from another company.